# How to parse a .gz file using logstash and store it in mongodb without using s3 plugin and without unzipping the file manually?

Tags: logstash

I tried altering the input file plugin having name 'file.rb' by adding this line:

```
@path = Gem::Package::TarReader.new(Zlib::GzipReader.open('/path/to/.gz'))
@path.rewind.
```

This gives an error

> can't convert Gem::Package::TarReader::Entry into String

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. One can gunzip the file and give it as input to the logstash command.
Example: echo gunzip -c yourFile.gz | bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin { } } output { stdout { } }'